# Is Google Business Profile APIs "List all reviews" deprecated/disabled

Tags: google-api, google-developer-tools, google-business

I want to use this API "List all reviews"  @ https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews, but I am not sure if it is deprecated/disabled as there is a message on the top of the page indicating:

> Update your Google Business Profile API integration before critical
> endpoints are disabled. Review the deprecation schedule and
> instructions to avoid disruptions starting in April 2022.

It mentioned which modules will be disabled, and it stayed the following:

- GetLocation
- CreateLocation
- DeleteLocation
- ListLocation

So does this include the https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews ? If the answer is yes, then which API I need to use to get the Reviews for our Google account?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yes.  Google has deprecated all of the My Business API's.